# Create 6 times 100 -matrix or DF with specfic column names in R

Tags: r

*Probably about 20 chars' solution. I want colnames to `matrix(...)` -object or alternative way to create 6x100 dataframe with zeros and colnames:*

```
matrix(rep(0,600),ncol=6)->M
```

where to access things with title-ids like`col$id` and now to access 97th element in col `a1` in the matrix, I want to do `M$a1[97]`. How?

**Errr**

```
> matrix(rep(0,600),ncol=6,nrow=100, colnames=c('q1','q2','a1','a2','s1','s2'))
Error in matrix(rep(0, 600), ncol = 6, nrow = 12, colnames = c("q1", "q2",  : 
  unused argument(s) (colnames = c("q1", "q2", "a1", "a2", "s1", "s2"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use the `dimnames` parameter in matrix to define column names when creating the matrix. dimnames should be a list of 2 or NULL.

```
M <- matrix(rep(0,600), ncol = 6, 
            dimnames = list(NULL, c('q1','q2','a1','a2','s1','s2')))
```

From the help page:

```
dimnames    
A dimnames attribute for the matrix: NULL or a list of length 2 giving the row and column
names respectively. An empty list is treated as NULL, and a list of length one as row
names. The list can be named, and the list names will be used as names for the dimensions.
```

Or set the colnames after the fact:

```
colnames(M) <- c('q1','q2','a1','a2','s1','s2')
```

2) Use the `[` indexing operator for matrices:

```
> M[97, "a1"]
a1 
 0
```

Comment: **Solution** = `"dimnames = list(NULL, c('q1','q2','a1','a2','s1','s2'))"` and good tip `(2)`. +1

Answer (score 1):

If everything else fails, you can consider reading the help page :)

`matrix()` wants `dimnanes=` as in

```
R> matrix(rep(0,18), ncol=6, 
+>        dimnames=list(NULL, c('q1','q2','a1','a2','s1','s2')))
     q1 q2 a1 a2 s1 s2
[1,]  0  0  0  0  0  0
[2,]  0  0  0  0  0  0
[3,]  0  0  0  0  0  0
R>
```

where the first argument to `dimnames` is a vector of row names.